# git pull: bad object from remote, yet remote fsck shows no error

Tags: git

I have a git repository in my home directory and a copy on an external HDD.  However, when I try to pull from `$HOME` to the HDD I get

```
remote: fatal: bad object afea5e5fc05d21431756099f941d776ca2d76b31
error: git upload-pack: git-pack-objects died with error.
fatal: git upload-pack: aborting due to possible repository corruption on the remote side.
remote: aborting due to possible repository corruption on the remote side.
fatal: protocol error: bad pack header
```

Back in the repository on $HOME, `git fsck --full afea5e5fc05d21431756099f941d776ca2d76b31` gives no output.

Where is this broken object?  Thanks.

Comment: try transfering the repo with git bundle

Comment: How did you make your copy? Was it a simple `copy`, or a proper `clone`. If you did a simple copy then all the paths to your 'remote' will be wrong when at the copy destination. Check the git config file.

Comment: Philip: I used clone.

edofic: oddly that works.  Also, transferring by pushing from $HOME to my central repo and then pulling back to the external drive over SSH works too.

Why on earth would the fact I'm pulling over the local filesystem make this difference?

Comment: The bad object could be local, or missing. You say _that_ one gives no output, do _others_ give some output? What does `git cat-file -p afea5e` say?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't test this now; I solved the problem by upgrading git.

Answer (score 0):

bad object with some hexadecimal number tends to mean that a `ta`g has an invalid reference number in it, but can also occur for some other cases as well.

Check your tags and run `fsck` without the sha-1

```
git fsck --full
```